# Is it possible to do ClickOnce Deployment with Apache?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, clickonce

Can I publish a winforms application using ClickOnce Deployment to an apache server?

When attempting to publish to an Apache Server I get this error:

> Failed to connect to
>   'http://10.200.0.80:8081/WinSync/'
>   with the following error: Unable to
>   open the Web site
>   'http://10.200.0.80:8081/WinSync/'. To
>   access Web sites on the local IIS Web
>   server, you must run Visual Studio
>   under an Administrator account in
>   order to have access to the IIS
>   metabase. Alternatively, install
>   FrontPage Server Extensions (FPSE) and
>   then grant FPSE access to users who
>   will run Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm sure the answer is yes, but did you install front page extensions on Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You add the mime types to the httpd.conf like the link JaredPar provided, and you set the Publishing Folder to the directory of the webfolder, and then the Installation Folder to it's equivalent URI

For example I currently have the publishing folder as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\WinSync\`
And the Installation Folder as
`http://10.200.0.80:8081/WinSync/`
I also told it to generate a publish.htm every time, I don't think that makes a difference though.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce doesn't have an inherent dependency on any web server that I know of.  It's deployment model is very flexible.  Really it just needs an accessible URI and a place to store it's bits.  You can in fact deploy to a file share if you'd like.  I run several internal applications this way.

So yes, there shouldn't be any restriction on deploying to Apache Servers as long as

1. You can actually get the bits onto the server
2. The URL they are parked at is visible to consumers.

This blog entry goes into detail on how you can deploy to Apache: http://blogs.msdn.com/josephkiran/archive/2009/01/06/clickonce-deployment-using-iis-apache-server-for-vsto.aspx

Comment: I went through the publish wizard and it complained that it couldn't access the IIS server.

Comment: @Malfist, can you add that information to your post?  It will be helpful in tracking down the problem.